# Python PyVISA module wont import

Tags: automation, pyvisa, dvm

New to Python, useing PyVISA for Agilent 34460A meter, when i try to import PyVISA i get errors.  I have discovered if use pyvisa (no caps) it imports, no error. Why does it import with no caps and as it actually is on the system as PyVISA it will not import?  Even went so far as using the python editor installed with python.

I tried every version python from 3.5 to current 3.11 during 3.11 discovered the (caps/nocaps) thing.  Running windows 10 on Dell XP8900 I7 machine.  I expected that import function would work with Caps as shown on the pip show command.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked on pypi and PyVisa doesn't seem to have an error list.

Anyway the problem seems to come from your computer, without seeing the installation error it's hard to tell which error you're facing.

I advise you to use a virtual environment (venv), you can create one with this command: `python -m venv venv_name` then you can use this command to activate the virtual environment (if you're on windows) `venv_name\Scripts\Activate` then install PyVisa again: `pip install PyVISA`.

if the problem persists you can contact the creators of PyVisa.